# HTML/CSS Table/Rows

Tags: html, css

and sorry for my bad English.
I have some table created on my page dynamicly, depenting on what a user have access to or not.
I create a table with 2 rows that is my header, and the in a nest for() I create all the other tables.
My Finall setup is something like that:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">Header 1</td>
    <td class="col2">Header 2</td>
    <td class="col3">Header 3</td>
    <td class="col4">Header 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">column 1 for access 1</td>
    <td class="col2">column 2 for access 1</td>
    <td class="col3">column 3 for access 1</td>
    <td class="col4">column 4 for access 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">column 1 for access 2</td>
    <td class="col2">column 2 for access 2</td>
    <td class="col3">column 3 for access 2</td>
    <td class="col4">column 4 for access 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">column 1 for access 2</td>
    <td class="col2">column 2 for access 2</td>
    <td class="col3">column 3 for access 2</td>
    <td class="col4">column 4 for access 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My CCS is

```
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-color: #aabcfe;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
  .tg td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: visible;
    word-break: normal;
    border-color: #aabcfe;
    color: #669;
    background-color: #e8edff;
  }
  .tg th {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
    border-color: #aabcfe;
    color: #039;
    background-color: #b9c9fe;
  }
    .tg .tg-column1{
      background-color: #e7ffe7;
      color: #000000;
      border-color: #000000;
      text-align: right;
      vertical-align: middle
    }
    .tg .tg-column2{
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #000000;
      border-color: #000000;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      top: -1px;
      will-change: transform
    }
    .tg .tg-column3{
      background-color: #e7ffe7;
      color: #000000;
      border-color: #000000;
      text-align: right;
      vertical-align: middle
    }
    .tg .tg-column4{
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #000000;
      border-color: #000000;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      top: -1px;
      will-change: transform
    }
```

The width of each colum in each table is diffrent.
Is there a way for all table column1 for example to have the some width equal to the max width of all tables?
Now I'm getting something the below picture
[image]

Comment: Yes! The way i'm thinking of is using JS to find the biggest width and applying this to all columns. However I guess you can also fix this by making a flex table. What do you prefer?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Can you point me to the right direction for flex tables?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://inlehmansterms.net/2014/10/11/responsive-tables-with-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You dont need JS or anything to achieve this.

Just make sure, you're staying in the same Table. (You should use thead and tbody anyway as per HTML5)

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">Header 1</td>
      <td class="col2">Header 2</td>
      <td class="col3">Header 3</td>
      <td class="col4">Header 4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">column 1 for access 1</td>
      <td class="col2">column 2 for access 1</td>
      <td class="col3">column 3 for access 1</td>
      <td class="col4">column 4 for access 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">column 1 for access 2</td>
      <td class="col2">column 2 for access 2</td>
      <td class="col3">column 3 for access 2</td>
      <td class="col4">column 4 for access 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbdoy>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">column 1 for access 2</td>
    <td class="col2">column 2 for access 2</td>
    <td class="col3">column 3 for access 2</td>
    <td class="col4">column 4 for access 2</td>
  </tr>
  </tbdoy>
</table>
```

"This will just automatically set the width of the broadest cell to all cells."

Comment: Change all first columns to "1" and see it doens't work.  I mean u have the same data in each column, ofcourse now they are the same width...

Comment: I'll post the question for you once more. I hope you understand: "Is there a way for ALL TABLES COLUMNS to have the width equal to the max width of all tables?"

Comment: Wow, okay. If you take this into consideration what the autor asks is impossible. Because the table would be getting bigger in the same time it does resize the first column. In Addition if you try it: https://jsfiddle.net/q8ue05po/1/ it actually fits. So?

Comment: If you think about setting each cell to the widest width (as in the picture), this would fill the screen with unnecessary space. But I understand now, you have understood the question literally. Therefore you're right!, even if im pretty sure, thats not what the autor meant.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question properly, but the CSS classes you listed there don't match your HTML classes. Setting a width on .col1 classes should ensure the first column of all tables should be equal. If you want it to be responsive to screen size, set a percentage.

An easier way to do this without setting a class on each td separately, is (assuming you have the same number of s on each ) to use `td:nth-child(1)` and set a width on that. This selects the first  child of each  and sets a width on that.

If there are any table headers on the first column, you need to set width for those separately using the same method but with `th:nth-child(1)`.

Another method that might be useful if you want to specify widths without using nth child, for multiple columns in a table is `<colgroup>`:

```
<colgroup>
<col class="1">
<col class="2">
<col class="3">
</colgroup>
```

The browser interprets the first  child of the `<colgroup>` to be the first column, second to be the second column, and so forth. Now you can set each width to each column (for tables that have a lot of columns, this would be useful, and more intuitive than `nth-child`). However, there aren't many CSS properties that can apply to `<col>` - I think there are only 4 at the moment (`border, background, width and visibility`), so you can't apply things like `text-align`.

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML code, you created 4 tables each has only 1 row and 4 columns.
In your CSS code, you used different classes other than specified in your HTML code.

If you wish your tables' vertical border match, you can set `width` attribute to fixed (`px`, `em`, `rem` (depending on the font-size of root or parent element)) units or relative (`%`, `vh`, `vw`) units so they verticall match/align.

Good luck!

Comment: Adding a fixed width doesn't make it dynamically

Comment: Sure it doesn't. For width to be dynamic, min-width and/or max-width are advised to be used.

Comment: Also not good advise. How would you set this min-width, max-width then?

Comment: For necessary units, for example min-width: 300px and max-width: 500px.

Comment: But I have text I want to print beyond 500px. Also some will we 300px other will be 500px. The question is the get the same width as the biggest width.

Comment: You want to print whole sentence in one line not going to the next line?